# insert 1000 records using LINQ

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-xml, linq-to-objects

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
 {
      PrivateMessage privateMessage = new PrivateMessage()
      {
          id=i
      };
      dc.PrivateMessages.InsertOnSubmit(privateMessage);
      dc.SubmitChanges(); 
 }
```

This method is suitable for insert 1000 records?

There are better ways to do this?

Comment: Yes there is a better way: don't use Linq for this kind of work. It's not designed for this. Use the `SqlBulkCopy` component for bulk inserts.

Comment: I would consider not using LINQ for the insert.  You could instead look at something like SqlBulkCopy.  Due to performance reason I had to remove some LINQ inserts from one of my applications and go with the bulk copy method instead.  Of course I was dealing with 100s of thousands of records...

Comment: SqlBulkCopy is a better way to do this. You should consider using SqlBulkCopy instead for its SqlBulkCopy advantages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah-- probably best not to do your `InsertOnSubmit` in a loop. Try:

```
List<PrivateMessage> messages = new List<PrivateMessage>();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
   messages.Add(new PrivateMessage() { id=i });
}

dc.PrivateMessages.InsertAllOnSubmit(messages);
dc.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

have dc.SubmitChanges() out of loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
           PrivateMessage privateMessage = new PrivateMessage()
            {
                id=i
            };
            dc.PrivateMessages.InsertOnSubmit(privateMessage);
}
           dc.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another one:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).ToList().ForEach(x =>             
            dc.PrivateMessages.InsertOnSubmit(new PrivateMessage(){id=x}));
dc.SubmitChanges();
```